# cannot find name in imported module

Tags: python

my directory structure is like the following:

```
a/
 - b/
    - __init__.py
    - settings.py
    - mymain.py
 - settings.py
```

a/settings.py

```
#the common names
ES_HOSTS = ["localhost"]
```

b/settings.py:

```
from a.settings import *
#the names that is specific to b.settings
```

b/main.py

```
import settings
print settings.ES_HOSTS
```

python tells me that

```
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ES_HOSTS'
```

Could you help to tell me how to debug this problem?

Comment: did you try running `b.settings` ? Are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think your path would work, as you are going out of the scope of Pythons search. `a.settings` is a level above `b.settings` and won't be looked at (`Python` doesn't search up a level - and as your calling everything from `mymain.py`, the starting point is within `b`) - either move the file so it has a different name but is in the same scope (so all under either `b` or `a`, instead of different nesting levels).

Or change the Python path by using `sys.path.append(path_to_module)`.

An alternative is to split `a` and `b` into separate non-nested folders on the same level, and have `mymain.py` above them, like so:

```
my_proj/
 - mymain.py
 - a/
    - __init__.py
    - settings.py
 - b/
    - __init__.py
    - settings.py
```

and have `mymain.py` use

```
import b.settings as settings
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation to me of the python path search pattern.